# Google Maps API v3 code not working

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The code below is used to show a map on a PHP page. Markers or pins are shown when a link for a particular location on a side bar is clicked, When a link is clicked the map is zoomed to the location of the link clicked. I had originally written the code in V2 and am now attempting to convert it to V3. The map is showing up on the page, but when I click the links the map does not retrieve its location. 
When the link is Clicked it calls the showme() function in the below code.

This is the JavaScript Code.

```
    var geoCoder = null;
    var marker = null;
    var center = false;
    var show_info = false;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.4032173, - 61.3719045),
            zoom: 9,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);
    }

  function showAddress(address,description) {
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:description});
      geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
      if (geoCoder) {
        geoCoder.getPosition()(
          address,
          function(point) {
            if (point){
              if(center) map.setCenter(point, 13);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker(point);
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                infowindow.open(point, description);
              });
              marker.setMap(marker);
                if(show_info) infowindow.open(point, description);
              }
            }
        );
      }
     geoCoder = null;
    }


    function showLatLng(lat,lng,description) {
            var point=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
            if (point){
              if(center) map.setCenter(point, 14);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:point,
                                           map: map});

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:description});

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                infowindow.open(point, description);
              });
              marker.setMap(maker);
                if(show_info)  infowindow.open(point, description);
              }
      }

    function showme(name, address, lat, lng, contact, Link) {
        var description = desc(name, address, contact, Link);
        center = true;
        show_info = true;
        if (lat || lng) showLatLng(lat, lng, description);
        else showAddress(address, description);
        return false;
    }

    function desc(name, address, contact, Link) {
        //var address = "<div class='googleTip'><div><h1>"+name+"</h1></div><p class='address'>"+address+"<br />"+contact+"<br />"+delivery+"</p><span class='mapLink'></span></div>";
        var Address = ["<div class='googleTip' style='color:#000000; padding:5px'><h3>",
        name, "</h3>", "<div>",
        address, "<br />",
        webLink, "</div></div>", ].join('');
        return Address;
    }
```

How do I fix this. I am frustrated with this.

Comment: In showAddress function, you use `geo.getPosition` instead of  `geoCoder.getPosition`. Is this the problem ?

Comment: There is no map.addOverlay(marker); in V3. Check the docs.

Comment: you could also remove the last `,` before the `.join('')`

Comment: It should be `google.maps.event.addListener(...)` in version-3.

Answer (score 0):

Your "showMe function is still using API v2 syntax. GMarker should be google.maps.Marker, GEvent.addListener should be google.maps.event.addListener, map.openInfowindow needs to be adjusted for the new syntax, [see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow), something like the below (not tested):

```
function showLatLng(lat,lng,description) {
        var point=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
        if (point){
          if(center_point) map.setCenter(point, 14);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:point,
                                           map: map});
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:description});

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infowindow.open(point, marker);
          });
          marker.setMap(map);
            if(show_info) infowindow.open(point, marker);
          }
  }
```

The callback function for the geocoder has the same problem.

Comment: I have edited the original code to show changes made. But it still is not working. When I click on the links on the page, the map does not show the location. I know this is a problem with the showme() function but I cant see it. Please help.

Comment: Did you fix the [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) syntax (I don't think there is a getPosition() method)? What javascript errors does the console report?

Comment: My google api console does not report any errors. I think its just a logic error.

Comment: Look at the documentation for [google.maps.Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder).  A jsfiddle with complete code and html might be helpful as well.

Comment: Do I need to put  a request and call back function in the geocoder? I have tried but its not working. Also is the showme function now in V3 format?